# Error in correlation matrix of a data frame

Tags: r

R version 3.5.1.
I want to create a correlation matrix with a Data frame that goes like this:

```
BGI      WINDSPEED  SLOPE 
4277.2   4.23        7.54
4139.8   5.25        8.63
4652.9   3.59        6.54
3942.6   4.42        10.05
```

I put that as an example but I have more than 20 columns and over 40,000 entries.

I tried using the following codes

```
corrplot(cor(Site.2),method = "color",outline="white")

Matrix_Site=cor(Site.2,method=c("spearman"))
```

but every time, the same warning appears:

> Error in cor(Site.2) : 'x' must be numeric

I would like to correlate every variable of the data frame with each other and create a graph and a table with it, similar to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Anthony_Okoh/publication/51732797/figure/tbl2/AS:601699584581645@1520467768929/Correlation-matrix-of-water-quality-parameters-Pearson-correlation-coefficients-r-of.png).

Comment: Usually this error happens when one of your columns is not numeric. Try `str(Site.2)` to see if youve forgotten to change them all to numeric. Also, check for missing values.

Comment: **Self promotion**: Is this what you want to achieve? `manymodelr::get_var_corr_(df,method="spearman")`